# In Python, how to use super for a class attribute?

Tags: python

Consider these two classes:

```
class A(object):
    name = "A"

class B(A):
    name = "Child of " + A.name
```

Simple. `A.name` will be "A" and `B.name` will be "Child of A".

But it seems wrong to hard code `A.name` into `B`'s definition of `name`. I naturally want to write something like:

```
class B(A):
    name = "Child of " + super(B).name
```

But that raises a `NameError` with `B` not yet being defined in the expression `super(B)`. (Also, I'm not sure whether it should/would be `super(B)` or `super(B, B)` or something else, but that's a moot point given the `NameError`.)

What's the right way to do this, i.e. use `super` in the definition of a class attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done inside the class definition, for the reason you discovered: inside the class definition, you don't have access to the class itself, since it's not defined yet.

You can do it with a class decorator, though (if you're using a version of Python with class decorators, which I think is 2.6 and up):

```
>>> class A(object):
...     name = "A"
>>> def makeAttr(cls):
...     cls.name = "Child of " + super(cls, cls).name
...     return cls
>>> @makeAttr
... class B(A):
...     name = "B"
>>> B.name
'Child of A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. If you must do this, you need to explicitly use A in the body of B.